# Installation error - PostGIS on Ubuntu 18

Tags: postgis, installation, error

I have installed PostgreSQL 11 on Ubuntu 18 and while creating PostGIS extension it gives this error.

> could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/postgis-2.5.so":
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/postgis-2.5.so: undefined symbol:
>   AllocSetContextCreate

The command I used to download PostGIS

```
apt install postgis postgresql-11-postgis-2.5
```

Comment: can you please let me know which version of geos you are using? you can try "geos-config --version" command in terminal to check the installed version of geos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is most likely due to older version of geos, you need to install latest version of geos, you can try`sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.6.2` to get latest version. Hope this answers your question.